# Is it possible to scroll automatically in UIPageViewController iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

Is it possible to scroll automatically in UIPageViewController iOS with Swift?
That means user no need to scroll manually. It will work automatically and also with infinite pages.

Comment: you can use `setViewControllers` method and make sure the first viewController is the next page

Comment: @rani yes its possible with NSTimer. for this you have to call some function with call  make ++ counter of page from NSTimer.

Answer (score 1):

You need set Timer.
Below code should write in viewDidLoad() Method

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: "moveToNextPageTwoSecond", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

This timer will call the moveToNextPageTwoSecond function every 2 seconds.

```
func moveToNextPageTwoSecond (){

    let pageWidth:CGFloat = CGRectGetWidth(self.scrollView.frame)
    let maxWidth:CGFloat = pageWidth * 4
    let contentOffset:CGFloat = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x

    var slideToX = contentOffset + pageWidth

    if  contentOffset + pageWidth == maxWidth{
        slideToX = 0
    }
    self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRectMake(slideToX, 0, pageWidth, CGRectGetHeight(self.scrollView.frame)), animated: true)
}
```

Comment: This question is nothing to do with `UIScrollView`

Comment: This could be the approved answer.
I Will add the swift 3.0 version

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll to a specific page (page X) in your `UIPageViewController` by using the following code:

```
// Get the View Controller for the page X of the Page View Controller and store in an array
let pageXViewController: UIViewController = pageXViewControllerAtIndex(X)!
let viewControllers: NSArray = [pageXViewController]
// Set the first page of the Page View Controller
pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score -1):

First rule of anything like this... check the documentation.

[UIPageViewController docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewCo%E2%80%A6)

You will see a method... `- setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:` with the description... `Sets the view controllers to be displayed.`

This is what you are looking for.

Comment: First rule of answering a question, read the question carefully. The author looks for an automatic scroll, e.g. on timer.

Comment: @A-Live first rule of making a rude, sarcastic and unnecessary comment and down voting an answer. Make sure you're right. This will scroll automatically and can be called with a timer. Which part of that are you incapable of understanding?

Comment: Repeating myself is not productive, read the original comment for the answer instead.

Comment: @A-Live ok. Don't repeat yourself. Instead explain why you think the function I answered with can't be used with a timer and doesn't scroll the uipageviewcontroller. Then, after that I'll explain why you're wrong.

Comment: It can and it should be used here, the point is that you picked the easiest part of the question and failed to at least mention the other parts.

Comment: @A-Live read the question... "Is it possible to scroll automatically in UIPageViewController iOS with Swift?" My answer shows them what to use. They already know they need a timer. By having the correct api (which my answer is the only one to provide) they should be able to build what they want. Then you decided to down vote it for some bizarre reason. Obviously Tometoyou's answer is much higher quality to you. Explain how his answer is better than this? Explain how the answer that randomly goes to uiscrollview is better than this?

Comment: @A-Live if you want to down vote. Then down vote. I really don't care. But don't leave sarcastic comments that show that your reason for down voting is wrong. That's just stupid. We are not here to write code for people. This guy has zero code. I have shown him which api to use. If he comes back and needs guidance on how to use a timer etc... then he can ask that in another question or just look it up.

Comment: First of all, don't make it personal. Even if you want to, SO comments section is not the place for that, vent with a buddy if you want to. Back to the discussed matter, you have all the feedback on the answer that you need, take it or leave it. I would really appreciate if you took all the wasted time to improve the answer.

Comment: @A-Live have a good day. Please go pester someone else. Also, don't tell me what I should or shouldn't do. I have clearly shown that your down vote and reason for it is a load of rubbish. You clearly have no idea what you're talking about here. Good bye :)